# Failed to startup : ubuntu--vg-root clean

Tags: 17.10, lvm

When I start my laptop on Ubuntu 17.10 64bit, I got this message :

> /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: clean, 438875/18989056 files, 29500073/75952128

PS: I first had too :

> WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to device scanning.

After setting use_lvmetad to 0 un /etc/lvm/lvm.conf , this WARNING disappeared.

I do not understand why it does that because when I stopped my laptop there was no issues.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a way to fix my issue :

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

And then I rebooted my laptop.

Comment: After trying lot of unwanted and advanced stuffs, this easily fixed the issue, thanks.